# How to configure MySQL data with php Zend framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am working with core php for at least one year. Now I want to use a framework and I decided to use Zend Framework. But I could not able to configure/use MySQL database with Zend Framework.

Can any one tell me how to do this or give a link or tutorial from where I can do it my own.

Thanks 
Enamul

Comment: Surely this is described in the documentation? What Zend Framework examples or code are you working with?

Comment: Surely you have found this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html ?

Comment: You might consider another framework because ZF1's development is very slow (only bug fixes) because of ZF2. My top choice would be Symfony2! If you don't, @ctrahey 's link is a very good starting point :)

Comment: I really like the zendcast series.  You could start here for Zend_Db: http://www.zendcasts.com/zend_db-insert-and-read/2009/04/

Comment: Browse your asked questions..in that you can find a accept icon(tick symbol) click on it if you think its the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just provided answer to similar question that might help get you started. The Zend_Db component can be confusing in the beginning because there are so many options for using it. In fact there at least 3 different ways just to connect to a database.

[How to use Zend Adapter to retrieve information from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336018/how-to-use-zend-adapter-to-retrieve-information-from-database/11357335#11357335)